# Symfony Form value not flushing with Selectpicker class

Tags: php, symfony, bootstrap-4, symfony4, symfony-forms

In Symfony 4 form I have a form field declared with EntityType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder->add('tags', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Saptag::class,
                'choice_label' => 'descr',
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                //'attr' => ['class' => 'selectpicker']
     ));
                ...
}
```

When form is submited my database is well updated. If I activate class 'selectpicker' then my field has the rendering I need in the template but field value do not update database when this class is used. No error occurs...

Any idea of how to handle that ?

EDIT: This issue occurs when form is placed crossed div element:

```
<div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Whatever entity or DTO you are using as data for the form... does it have a `setTags()` method?

Comment: Do you have any syfony form erros in the debug toolbar ?

Comment: I had no issue in the debug toolbar. I found the answer on the bootstrap-select Github:[https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1342 ]